# Database migration error-magento 1.9.3.9 to magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento, database-migration

I am getting error in magento database migration.
I want to migrate database from magento 1.9.3.9 to magento 2.3.4.

I am getting error :

> [2020-03-27 13:09:17][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity
>   check][step: Settings Step]: started 100%
>   [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec [2020-03-27
>   13:09:18][ERROR]: Integrity check failed due to "core_config_data"
>   document does not exist in the destination resource
>
> [NOTICE]: Please check if table names uses prefix, add it to your
>   config.xml file
>
> [2020-03-27 13:09:18][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity
>   check][step: Stores Step]: started 100% [============================]
>   Remaining Time: < 1 sec [2020-03-27 13:09:19][ERROR]: Source documents
>   are not mapped: core_store,core_store_group,core_website [2020-03-27
>   13:09:19][ERROR]: Destination documents are not mapped:
>   store,store_group,store_website [NOTICE]: You can use --auto or -a
>   option to ignore not mapped differences between source and destination
>   to continue migration

Please find attached screenshot for more

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnbU9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Magento allows us to define prefixes for tables. In your case, the destination table `core_config_data` does not exist. It is possible that there is such a table, but it's not correctly identified due to the wrong prefix. Make sure that you have the proper value for `destination_prefix` in config.xml. Another possibility is that the destination database is empty when data is attempted to be copied. If this is the situation, then make sure that the destination tables are properly initialized before the copy occurs.

Anyway, backup everything before you do this so you can recover if you encounter unexpected behavior.